# NVim does not highlight syntax unless I'm logged in as root

Tags: neovim

My config file for vim under `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` looks like this

```
:set ignorecase
:set smartcase
:set nu

:let $VIMRUNTIME="/usr/share/nvim/runtime"
:let $VIM="/usr/share/nvim"
:let $NVIM="/usr/share/nvim"
```

I need to set up those variables, otherwise they default to `/home/.vimrc` which is not present (and shouldn't be).

When I enter nvim and run `:syntax on` I get this message:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim:
line   42:
E216: No such group or event: filetypedetect BufRead
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I open the same file with `sudo nvim <file>` syntax highlighting works fine. I've checked those 3 environment variables in the sudo version and they have the exact same value as the config file - if I remove/rename the config file, those variables stay the same in the sudo version.

Is there a way for me to solve this syntax issue when not running nvim as root?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please post line 42 from `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim`.

Comment: Are you using Neovim or Vim?

Comment: I'm using neovim. Line 42 is `doautoall filetypedetect BufRead`It's pretty much the same as the file here https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim except mine is an older version that has two fewer comment lines.

Comment: Then be clear about it. Vim and Neovim are two different and increasingly incompatible programs so mixing them up in your communication is not a good idea. Also, a) Neovim, like Vim, knows where to find its runtime files so setting those environment variables is useless (unless you do weird things), and b) Neovim doesn't source `~/.vimrc`, only Vim does, hence my request for clarification. As-is, the question is a mess, and your setup looks like it is a mess, too. Straighten it out and you are likely to solve your problem without external help.

Comment: My problem came from the fact that I was trying to share settings between vim and nvim. What I was hoping to find here is whether there was some config file that's specific to root that I could use to restore my own. Seems those default variables are baked in and they're changed somewhere along the way. I searched for them using `sudo egrep -r '/home/.vimrc' / 2>/dev/null` and found the problem. Now it's sorted.